# Can it be beneficial to use a canonical tag from your homepage to another website page if you want to rank that page?

Tags: canonical-url

I want to rank for keyword 'python cursus' with webpage https://pythoncursus.nl/python-cursus/.

Given the fact that it's an exact match domain, I think Google is confused about which page to rank. And also probably reluctant to rank the page because it looks like I want to rank quickly by stuffing keywords.

Now I came up with the idea to put a canonical tag on the homepage directing to https://pythoncursus.nl/python-cursus/. I'm aware the consequence of this is that the homepage won't come up in google anymore. I'm fine with that.

My idea is that it's clear for Google that https://pythoncursus.nl/python-cursus/ has to be ranked and also I hope the homepage passes some link juice to the page by putting the canonical tag in.

Does anyone have experience with using a canonicalized tag away from the homepage? Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 3):

Canonical tag is meant for identical pages. It is a way of telling Google that one or more pages are identical and that you want to rank one of those pages. I don't think your use case fits that criteria.

Reference: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes that is the main use of canonical tags. However, a canonical tag can also be used for pages that are targeting the same "user intent" but have different content. Both the homepage and the specific page have the intent to sell python courses (same search intent). So I think it can be applied. But my main question is whether people have experience with what happens when you point a canonical tag away from the homepage of a website.

Comment: Unless the pages are 90% identical Google just ignores canonical tags. The tag will have no effect. There is really no benefit for having a page with keywords in the URL either. You won't get better rankings just because you are URL path has the keywords in it then you would with the homepage.

Comment: @RikVanDerWardt Canonical doesn't work based on "user-intent" but "identical content". However, since you ask about using on the home page, yes you can use provided home page content is identical to the specific page you are talking about. In case, there are even cases of cross-domain canonical implementations. An article about this is here: https://moz.com/blog/cross-domain-rel-canonical-seo-value-cross-posted-content